# My OpenGL program only uses the last texture loaded (C++)

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping, texture2d

I have this issue with my loader:

```
int loadTexture(char *file)
{
    // Load the image
    SDL_Surface *tex = IMG_Load(file);
    GLuint t;

    cout << "Loading image: " << string(file) << "\n";
    if (tex) {
        glGenTextures(1, &t); // Generating 1 texture
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, t); // Bind the texture
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, tex->w, tex->h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex->pixels); // Map texture
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); // Set minifying parameter to linear
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); // Set magnifying parameter to linear
        SDL_FreeSurface(tex); // Free the surface from memory
        cout << "   > Image loaded: " << string(file) << "\n\n";
        return t; // return the texture index
    }
    else {
        cout << "   > Failed to load image: " << IMG_GetError() << "\n\n";
        SDL_FreeSurface(tex); // Free the surface from memory
        return -1; // return -1 in case the image failed to load
    }

}
```

It loads the images just fine but only the last image loaded is used when drawing my objects:

```
textTest = loadTexture("assets/test_texture_64.png");
textTest2 = loadTexture("assets/test_texture2_64.png");
textTest3 = loadTexture("assets/test_texture3_64.png");
textTest4 = loadTexture("assets/test_texture4_64.png");
```

Texture files:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPmFX.png

The program running:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI70C.png

Before drawing an object I use glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, t) where t is the name of the texture I want to use. I'm new to OpenGL and C++ so I'm having trouble understanding the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if loadTexture returns different texture IDs when you load the textures. Then you need to be sure that you bind the right textures onto the object using `glBindTexture(...)` which you say you are doing already.

How are you drawing your object right now? Is multi texturing involved? Be sure to have the right `glPushMatrix` / `glPopMatrix` calls before and after drawing your object.

From looking at your loader it looks correct to me although you do not `glEnable` and `glDisable` `GL_TEXTURE_2D` but that should not matter.

Comment: I've solved the issue, I was binding the texture in the glBegin block instead of outside of it. Thanks for the answer though. How do I close my question?